# Change Bundle item price on PDP

Tags: magento2

I would like to change the price of the bundle product items before its has been added to cart and recalculate the bundle product price and changing the bundle item price on the PDP .How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try catalog price rules and target specific SKU's or categories.